# Describe an orthoplex as a polyhedron

Tags: polyhedra, discrete-geometry

How can I define a orthoplex as a polyhedron?

The definitions that I am using are:

- $n$-dimensional [orthoplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope): $$O_{n} = \mbox{conv}\left\{e_1, -e_1, e_2, -e_2,\dots, e_n, -e_n \right\}$$ where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the vectors of the standard basis. $\mbox{conv}$ denotes a convex combination of finitely many elements in $O_{n}$.
- polyhedron $$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq b\}$$

I tried to get an arbitrary element in the orthoplex and write it as convex combination, but I'm struggling doing this and don't know how I can write that to a matrix formula.

Comment: There is  a lot of information about this polytope at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope . If that does not provide what you need, [edit] the question to tell us more precisely what you want in a "matrix formula".

Comment: Thank you for the links Ethan and Rodrigo.  I do understand the question now and I also understand this subject better now